# Why summary field value in the main report does not pass to the subreport?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report in which I have added a sub report.In the main report,I have a field for standard score in the details section,I need to find out it's average(for which,I have used a summary field) and pass it as a parameter to the sub report where it will be linked to the sub report field - AverageScore.For achieving this,I right clicked on the sub report,selected the Change Subreport Links option and from there I linked the main report summary field to the sub report field averagescore.As a result this was the selection formula for the subreport:

```
{AggregateKey.AverageScore} = {?Pm-Avg of ResultSheet.StandardScore}
```

The preview does not show anything in the subreport.But just to try out things, when I change the linking and pass any other value as a parameter, say some other field like

```
{AggregateKey.AverageScore} = {?Pm-ResultSheet.TotalScore}
```

Or simply any other number,then I see the sub report displaying values which tells me that values are being passed.But why does that not work when I use a summary field as a parameter?

Comment: If linking is not working have you tried using shared variable to pass data to sib report?

Comment: @Siva , I have tried using shared variable in the selection formula for the subreport, but I get an error 'shared variables can only be used while printing'.

Comment: can you post your formula...

Comment: yeah sure @Siva , the original selection formula that I used for the subreport is {AggregateKey.AverageScore} = {?Pm-Avg of ResultSheet.StandardScore}, and later I used shared variables and tried to change the formula to {AggregateKey.AverageScore}=Shared numbervar x;

Comment: your formula is wrong change like this: `Shared numbervar x:={AggregateKey.AverageScore};`

Comment: @Siva I am getting an error :'A boolean is required here.'

Comment: have you used the same formula? can you paste here?... you shouldn't get that error...

Comment: @Siva Shared numbervar x:={AggregateKey.AverageScore};,this is the formula I am using,I have copied it from your previous comment.

Comment: ok then where are you writing this formula? that depends

Comment: @Siva, I am writing this in the record selection formula for the sub report.

Comment: that shouldn't be written in record selection formula... create a formula and write there

Comment: @Siva I need to use the records in the subreport to be displayed in accordance with the values in the main report therefore I am using this formula in the record selection formula.Writing this as a standalone formula probably won't serve my purpose.

Comment: It would server.. if you link the share number variable formula to link or shared number value in sub report...

Comment: @Siva What do you gain by passing the shared variable to the subreport instead of just the value? It seems like that's just adding necessary complexity to the report.

Comment: @Ryan.. if you look at the above conversation.. user is trying to assign the value to the shared variable in `record selection`... my approach is create a formula and pass the formula to the sub report which will serve the purpose... Also if that doesn't serve the purpose you can get some value to the sub report using shared variable and you can do some manuplation to the get the things working...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the reason you're not getting any matching records in the subreport is because of the precision of your calculated average from the main report; the `Average()` function will result in a numerical value to a certain number of decimals that may not match exactly what is in `{AggregateKey.AverageScore}`.

For example, your main report has the scores in 3 records of 1, 2, and 4 which would result in the value of `Average({ResultSheet.StandardScore})` being `2.33333...` which is a very difficult number to use correctly in an equality comparison without first rounding the value off in some way.

Comment: I have already rounded off the average. In fact when I tried to pass the rounded off average to the subreport and display it using a standalone formula, I saw it being displayed in rounded off format.So  I think rounding off is not an issue here.

Comment: I have found the solution, all that I needed to do was change the record  selection formula to {AggregateKey.AverageScore} = round({?Pm-Avg of ResultSheet.StandardScore}).Because I did not have the value of average score rounded off in the selection formula,I was not getting matching records in the subreport.It's done now.Thank you Siva and Ryan for your time and help.

Comment: By default, CR will not display numeric values to a very high precision. The value of a field could be `2.3333333...` but it will display as `2` or `2.33` on the report itself and can easily mess you up while debugging.